# Gambler's Ruin with unfair coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I was solving this famous problem which reads:

> You start with N Dollars.
> Each turn, you toss a coin for each dollar you have and you double it if you win, otherwise, you lose it. You go on like this.
> What is the probability of losing all of your money?

You solve the problem in the following way:

1. You notice that, $$P(\text{Ruin having N dollars}) = (P(\text{ruin having 1 dollar}))^N$$
2. calling $ e:= P(\text{ruin having 1 dollar}) $  you set the recursive expression

$$
e = p_l + p_w e^2 
$$

in which $p_l$ is the probability of losing and $p_w$ is the probability of winning (so that, you have now two coins and you have to lose both of them).

3. Setting $p_l = p_w = 1/2$ one has $e = 1$, which means that if you play this game forever you will lose eventually.

This is a standard problem and it is pretty famous.

I wanted to generalize the problem for unfair coins. In particular, I wanted to find the value of $p_w$ for which the probability $e$ is not zero.
So, I solved the equation for general $p_w$ and $p_l = 1 - p_w$ and what you get is that you always have two solutions, namely:

$$
e_1 = \frac{p_l}{p_w};  \quad e_2 = 1
$$

- When $p_w <1/2$, $e_1$ is larger than $1$: we can exclude this solution because it is not in $(0,1)$, the valid range for probability. We still have $1$ as a solution, which implies that we will always lose for all of our money.
- But when $p_w > 1/2$, $e_1$ is in (0,1), meaning that it is an acceptable solution. In fact, for $p_w=1$ you got $e_1=0$, according with the intuition. **The trouble is that $e_2$ is still a valid solution.**

Is this correct? And should we interpret the fact that we have two valid solutions in that regime, one of which leads to certain ruin?

Comment: Great question! This confusion arises because you are treating limits unrigorously.

Comment: You mean the recursive equation for obtaining $e$?

Answer (score 3):

You got that if $e$ is probability of ruin having $1$ dollar, then it satisfies your equation. It doesn't mean that any $e$ that satisfies this equation is probability of ruin. Extreme case: this probability also satisfy equation $e = e$, but clearly not all solutions of this equation are probabilities of ruin.

To see that $e \neq 1$ if $p_w > \frac{1}{2}$, we probably need some limit theorems. For simplicity, assume we bet on one dollar at a time (given sequence of coin flips, it lead to the same result of ruining or not).

Let $\overline X_n$ be fraction of wins after $n$ flips. Strong law of big numbers say that $P(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \overline X_n = p_w) = 1$. From definition of limit it implies that for some $N$, $P(\exists n > N: \overline X_n < \frac{1}{2}) < 1$.

Obviously we can get to $2N$ dollars with non-zero probability. After that, we have non-zero probability of never losing more than half times except may be in the next $N$ flips, which isn't going to ruin us. So, there is non-zero probability of never losing all our money, and so $e \neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

While looking at the wikipedia page for gambler's ruin, I actually saw that there is a [section on unfair coin flipping,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Unfair_coin_flipping). It returns undefined when I plug in a *fair* coin ($\frac{0}{0}$), but if I plug in an only very slightly unfair coin, p=0.50001,q=0.49999, I get $P_1=0.50004$, or just $0.00004$ off from a fair coin which scans.

\begin{aligned}P_{1}&={\frac {1-({\frac {p}{q}})^{n_{2}}}{1-({\frac {p}{q}})^{n_{1}+n_{2}}}}\\[5pt]P_{2}&={\frac {1-({\frac {q}{p}})^{n_{1}}}{1-({\frac {q}{p}})^{n_{1}+n_{2}}}}\end{aligned}

Comment: For a fair coin you should be plugging in $\frac {\frac 12}{\frac 12}$ to the formula.  That is $1$, so is not undefined.  It leads to the correct result

Comment: @RossMillikan bittahProfessional is correct here.